# Get string without escape character in model

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have to send string to another app without HTML interpolation, but escape character '\' always stay on my string. For example:

The user write this on the form: `var => \test\Test\%`

I receive this when I call the BDD var

```rb
var
=>"\\test\\Test\\%"
```

I tried to remove one '\' but ruby refused

```rb
var.gsub("\\", "\")
=> syntax error, unexpected end-of-input
```

So I tried another way and find one with instance_eval:

```rb
object.instance_eval('"'+var+'"')
=> "\testTest%"
```

It works! But only on lowercase ... On uppercase or with special car it remove all escape character ...

Can you help me to get this result:

```rb
var
=>"\test\Test\%"
```

Comment: This is one of the most commonly asked questions from new developers in many languages... The short answer is that **there aren't any extra black-slashes**. and you *don't need to do anything* with `gsub` or similar.

Comment: @TomLord ok but the other app recived it with the extra-back-slashes ... And don't know how send it properly. On my view the var is correctly interpreted but don't when i send it.

Comment: No, it didn't. There *aren't any extra back-slashes*.

Comment: How do you represent a new-line when declaring a string? `x = "\n"`. So a backslash is an escape character; it means "Look out; this isn't an actual character, but it's a special placeholder to change the meaning of what's about to come next".

Comment: In this case I have to save some Widows path how can I do? In this case the backslash isn't for escape but is belongs to the var.

Comment: So how do you represent a literal backslash when declaring a string? `x = "\\"`. This string doesn't contain two back-slashes; it contains **one**. The declaration syntax doubles it, to avoid ambiguity.

Comment: Similarly, when *inspecting a variable*, ruby will show the backslashes "doubled" like this. Only to avoid developer ambiguity; not because there are actually double-backslashes in the string.

Comment: Long story short: `var = "\\test\\Test\\%"`. Now compare the following: `puts var` and `puts var.inspect`. There is not two backslashes; there is one. But if you **inspect** it, you see two.

Comment: I know I tried it long time but when i send it I have the 2 backslashes recieved, I know it really have only one of them

Comment: For example, `"\t"` is special syntax for a **TAB** (whitespace) character. So how do you distinguish between a literal backslash followed by the letter `t`, and a tab character? Backslash-t is represented as `\\t`, and a tab is `\t`. That's why when you **inspect** your string above, it shows `"\\test...."`, not `"\test..."`

Comment: No, you **don't** have two back-slashes received. When you "call the BDD variable" `var`, you are **inspecting** it. So it shows double-backslash. But there is only 1 backslash. As I said above, see what happens when you call `puts var` instead.

Comment: I know all that but it doesn't resolved my problem. Yes when I call it, when I puts or when i send it in html view but no when I send it. Maybe problem of save or other way? No method to save puts var and not send BDD var whithout treatment?

Comment: Where is your code that "sends the variable"? What do you mean by "send"? How can I reproduce the problem?

Comment: I have to send, when I deploy my service, table of hash to other app who interpret that on job. In my model I collect all data I need (so my var exemple)

Comment: I'll ask again: How can I reproduce the problem? If you don't provide reproduction steps, there's little chance i can help.